# Determining if two strings are anagrams

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge, complexity

> Two strings are said to be anagrams of each other if the letters of
>   one string may be rearranged to make the other string. For example,
>   the words 'elvis' and 'lives' are anagrams.
>
> In this problem you’ll be given two strings. Your job is to find if
>   the two strings are anagrams of each other or not. If they are not
>   anagrams then find the lexicographically smallest palindrome (in
>   lowercase alphabets) that may be appended to the end of either one of
>   the two strings so that they become anagrams of each other.
>
> The lower and upper case letters are considered equivalent. The number
>   of spaces or any other punctuation or digit is not important.
>
> One string is called lexicographically smaller than another if, at the
>   first position where they differ the first one has smaller alphabet.
>   For example, the strings 'hello' and 'herd' first differ at the third
>   alphabet; 'l' is smaller than 'r', so 'hello' is lexicographically
>   smaller than 'herd'.
>
> A Palindrome is a string that is the same when read forward or
>   backward. For example, the string 'bird rib' is a palindrome, whereas
>   'hello' is not.
>
> **Input:**
>
> The first line of the input contains a number T, the number of test
>   cases. T test cases follow. Each test case consists of two lines, one
>   string in each line.
>
> **Output:**
>
> For each test case output a single line. Print ‘YES’ (without the
>   quotes) if the two strings are anagrams of each other. If they are
>   not, then print the lexicographically smallest palindromic string as
>   discussed above. If no such string exists, then print ‘NO LUCK’
>   (without the quotes).
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> \$1 \le T \le 100\$
>
> \$1 \le \text{length of the strings} \le 100\$

- [Input file](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/epiphanyapril/problems/anagrams-1/input-e8c9147.txt)
- [Matched output file](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/epiphanyapril/problems/anagrams-1/output-e8c9170.txt)

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * Created by ankur on 20-10-2015.
 */
public class Anagrams {

    private static final String NO_LUCK = "NO LUCK";
    private static final String YES = "YES";
    public static void main(String... str) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int totalInput = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(totalInput);
        while (totalInput > 0) {
            totalInput--;
            String inputString1 = reader.readLine().trim().toLowerCase();
            String inputString2 = reader.readLine().trim().toLowerCase();
            String result = isAnagramPossible(inputString1, inputString2);
            output.append(result);
            output.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private static String isAnagramPossible(String a, String b){
        int[] returnedArray = isAnagram(a,b);
        /*System.out.println(returnedArray.length);
        for (int i:returnedArray){
            System.out.println(i);
        }*/
        int sum = 0,oddCount = 0;
        for (int i:returnedArray) {
            if ((i & 1) != 0){
                oddCount += 1;
            }
            sum += i;
        }
        if(sum == 0){
            return YES;
        }

        // Handling summing 1 case otherwise will get
        // java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in
        // constructPalindrome function
        else if(sum == 1){
            for (int i= 0; i < 26; i++){
                if (returnedArray[i] == 1){
                    return String.valueOf((char)('a' + i));
                }
            }
        }
        else if(oddCount > 1){
            return NO_LUCK;
        }
        System.out.println("Test");
        String palindromeAdd = constructPalindrome(returnedArray);



       return palindromeAdd;
}

    /*
    Constructing the palindrome string
     */
    private static String constructPalindrome(int[] charFrequenciesDiff){
        Character[] palindrome;
        System.out.println("Test");
        List<Character> characterList= new ArrayList<>();
        char midChar = ' ';
        boolean handleOdd = false;
        for (int i = 0; i< 26; i++ ){
            int total=charFrequenciesDiff[i];
            if((total & 1) == 1){
                handleOdd = true;
                total -= 1;
                midChar = (char)('a' + i);
            }
            while (total>0){
                total--;
                characterList.add((char)('a' + i)); //
            }
        }

        palindrome = characterList.toArray(new Character[characterList.size()]);
        int palindromeLen = palindrome.length;
        Arrays.sort(palindrome);
        if (palindromeLen == 1 || palindrome[0] == palindrome[palindromeLen - 1]){
            String str1= Arrays.toString(palindrome);
            str1 = str1.substring(1, str1.length()-1).replaceAll(", ", "");
            return str1 ;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



            int i =0;
            while(i < palindromeLen){
                sb.append(palindrome[i]);
                i += 2;
            }
            StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(sb);

        // Handle Odd case.
        if(handleOdd){
                sb.append(midChar);
            }
            sb.append(reverse.reverse());
            return sb.toString();

    }

    private static int[] isAnagram(String a, String b){
        int[] returnArray = new int[26];
        char[] a1 = new char[26];
        char[] a2 = new char[26];
        Arrays.fill(returnArray,0);
        Arrays.fill(a1, ' ');
        Arrays.fill(a2, ' ');
        char[] aArray = a.toCharArray();
        char[] bArray = b.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0, len = a.length(); i < len; i++ ){
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(aArray[i])) {
                int pos = (int) aArray[i] - (int) 'a';
                a1[pos] += 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0, len = b.length(); i < len; i++ ){
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(bArray[i])) {
                int pos = (int) bArray[i] - (int) 'a';
                a2[pos] += 1;
            }
        }

        int j =0;
        boolean is_true = true;

        while (j < 26 && is_true){
            if (a1[j] == a2 [j]){
                j = j+ 1;
            }
            else {
                is_true = false;
            }
        }

        if (!is_true){
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
                returnArray[i] = Math.abs(a1[i] - a2[i]);
            }
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Output time: 0.1619sec

How can I further improve the performance of this code in terms of time? Avoid repetitions if I did it somewhere. Also, lambdas elude me.

Comment: People Down-voting . care to give a reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that pops in my mind is the naming you used. For example, from a method called `isAnagramPossible` I'd expect to receive a `bool` and not a string. The same from `isAnagram`.

In the `isAnagram` method the `returnArray` variable should be renamed IMO as the name is not so meaningful. The same regarding `is_true`.

Also, commented code is only confusing. I'd remove it.

In addition:

```
    for (int i = 0, len = a.length(); i < len; i++ ){
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(aArray[i])) {
            int pos = (int) aArray[i] - (int) 'a';
            a1[pos] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0, len = b.length(); i < len; i++ ){
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(bArray[i])) {
            int pos = (int) bArray[i] - (int) 'a';
            a2[pos] += 1;
        }
    }
```

is repeated code (the two cycles are almost the same) and could be transformed in a method.

Other things seem ok.

Answer (score 1):

## Method names

```
private static String isAnagramPossible(String a, String b) { ... }

private static int[] isAnagram(String a, String b) { ... }
```

The Java convention for method names starting with `is` suggests that they should return a `boolean` value. You may want to consider renaming them as such:

```
private static String check(String a, String b) { ... }

private static int[] getDifference(String a, String b) { ... }
```

## Checking for differences

I think the (renamed) `getDifference(String, String)` method can be improved. Currently, there's just too much 'steps' to create the necessary `int[]` arrays, loop through the `String`s to populate said arrays, and them computing the differences. Instead of diving straight to `int[]` arrays, you can consider constructing a 'letter map' first, get the differences, and then generate the desired `int[]` array result. This is assuming you still want to stick to that type for the `constructPalindrome()` method.

```
private static int[] getDifference(String a, String b) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map = toLetterMap(a);
    toLetterMap(b).forEach((i, c) -> map.merge(i, c, (x, y) -> Math.abs(x - y)));
    int[] result = new int[26];
    map.forEach((i, c) -> result[i - 'a'] = c.intValue());
    return result;
}

private static Map<Integer, Long> toLetterMap(String v) {
    return v.chars().filter(Character::isLetter).map(Character::toLowerCase).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

**For the `toLetterMap(String)` method:**

1. Call [`String.chars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) to get an `IntStream` of 'characters'.
2. Filter only for letters using [`Character.isLetter(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-int-), and then for consistency [`toLowerCase(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-int-) as well, so you may want to do all the `String` normalization here instead of your `main()` method.
3. Convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` using [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--), so that we can do a [`groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to get our 'letter map'.

**For the `getDifference(String, String)` method:**

1. Call `toLetterMap(String)` on the first `String` to get an initial `Map` object `map`.
2. [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) of the `Map` entries from the second call to `toLetterMap(String)`, we [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) them into `map` accordingly.
3. Finally, create the `int[]` array and populate it, as your original handling.

## Handling edge cases

```
// Handling summing 1 case otherwise will get
// java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in
// constructPalindrome function
else if(sum == 1) { ... }
```

I think this might be better handled in the `constructPalindrome` method then, so that the method body of the (renamed) `check(String, String)` gets the difference in `String`s from `getDifference(String, String)`, and calls `constructPalindrome(int[])` if there are differences. There is thus no special handling 'dangling' in the method.

## Miscellaneous

```
System.out.println("Test");
```

You don't need that. :) You may want to pay attention to commented code (delete them as early as possible?) and also to redundant empty lines.